# terminal aborts when process finishes running with non-zero return value

Tags: terminal

My terminal is aborting when it encounters CTRL-Z:

```
Last login: Thu Aug 13 11:13:51 on ttys000
mymac:~ snowch$ sleep 10
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 10

[Process completed]
```

Sometimes I don't see the `[Process completed]` message - the terminal just closes.  Also, it doesn't seem to matter what command is running.  The same behavior happens with vim.

I also get the same behavior with iTerm2.

This behavior started happening out of the blue.

Any idea what is going wrong?

--**Update**--

I just tried entering the sleep command again, this time I forgot the time parameter:

```
mymac snowch$ sleep
usage: sleep seconds

[Process completed]
```

The terminal has interpreted this exit value as meaning that the process has finished.

Comment: You may want to check out [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/262942/whats-different-between-ctrlz-and-ctrlc-in-unix-command-line) and [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/476873/what-is-effect-of-ctrl-z-on-a-unix-linux-application). Is it possible that your process actually completes before you try to suspend it? Is your terminal actually Quitting when you press the keys?

Comment: The `[Process completed]` message is generated by Terminal and indicates that the shell itself (which was running in the Terminal window) has terminated. Is has nothing to do with the exit code of any command run inside the shell. Did you change anything in your bash startup files recently? Can you move them all out of the way and try again?

Comment: @patrix - thank you.  There was an error in my `~/.profile`.